# 2 внутренних div получаются под внешним

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему такое может быть: я пытаюсь расположить текст в 2 колонки, для этого сделала 1 внешний див и 2 внутренних, но получается, что выводится так - сначала внешний див на всю ширину, но в высоту нулевой, а под ним, уже снаружи, друг под другом - 2 внутренних.

Код:

```
<div id="vneshn" style=" height:100%; border:#000000; border-style:dashed">

    <div style="  border:#000000; border-style: double; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:5px;line-height:17px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-left:15px; margin-right:10px; float: left; width: 350px;color: #999999; font-size:11px;"><? echo $perv_kol ?></div>

    <div style=" border:#000000; border-style: double; margin-top:10px;  margin-bottom:5px; line-height:17px; margin-left:10px; float: left; width: 350px;color: #999999; font-size:11px;font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><? echo $vtor_kol ?></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю на вопрос почему?! Потому что вы используется float: left; он и перебивает стиль. Попробуйте вместо float: left; поставить display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; поставьте это во внутренние дивы.

Answer (score 3):

1. Либо добавьте внутрь внешнего div'а в конец `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, либо задайте ему стиль `overflow:auto`. [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html).
2. Ширина внешнего блока у вас не задана. Поэтому если две колонки не будут помещаться во внешнем блоке по-горизонтали, то второй блок будет переноситься. Задайте внешнему блоку необходимую ширину.

Answer (score 1):

Сама нашла: чтобы внешний див растягивался по высоте внутренних, необходимо ему выставить свойство `overflow:hidden`.